# SQL connection slow then becomes fast - SSMS

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

I'm working from my laptop, hard wired to the network, not using wifi. Using SSMS, I connect to a SQL Server and it connects in 1-2 minutes but I've seen it take 4-5 minutes. No timeouts, nothing in sql server logs, no errors. The connection just takes its time.

Wait some minutes, sometimes 15 sometimes longer, I try my connection again and it connects immediately.

What gives? I've spoken to my network team and no one else on my subnet has the same issues. Network team says it is something to do with my machine but gives me no direction on how to fix the issue.

Has anyone seen this issue before? If so, were you able to resolve it and what steps did you take?  Thank you!

*I've uninstalled SSMS and reinstalled the most recent version with no resolution.
**https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt238290.aspx

Comment: Not sure if it can make any difference, but have you compared if there is a difference with windows authentication and SQL Server authentication?

Comment: Why do you assume that something is wrong with SSMS? Connections typically happen in *seconds* so there is definitely something wrong with your infrastructure. Where is the server? On your local network, a remote server? Can you ping it? Why did you tag the question with `connection-string`?

Comment: BTW this is out of scope for SO. This is an infrastructure question, which means that you should ask this at serverfault or dba.stackexchange.com. This also means that *your admins* are the ones that know how to investigate this. Anything we tell you here they should already know and try. Perhaps your DNS has issues? They can check it faster. Slow remote connection or VPN? The same.

Comment: Your network is bad, or your domain controller is bad, or your server is out of resources, or your computer has malware, a particularly terrible virus scanner, a problem in the Winsock configuration, a bad combination of updates, or <insert other issue here that takes digging and has no universal solution>. SSMS, happily, is almost certainly *not* the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a connection string with an IP address or a network name e.g MYSERVER or whatever. Try doing some ping tests to the IP address of the instance and also to the server name and look for inconsistencies:

```
ping -t <IP address or host name>
```

If the IP is consistently fine but connection to the name is slow then it could well you have a DNS resolution issue somewhere and that it's slow resolving the network name back to the IP address of the instance so that you can connect.

1-2 minutes to connect to anything is VERY slow though I'd expect a few seconds max. You have an infrastructure rather than SSMS problem.